# does delete[ ] deep deletes a structure in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, struct

Suppose if I have an array of structures which in turn has dynamically allocated arrays in them, does delete[] deep deletes everything I said above?

For example, Consider I have this structure:

```
struct A
{
  char* name;
  float* data;
  int** image;
};
```

some place in my code I create

```
A** array = new A[n];
```

and I allocate memory for all structures in my array by

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  array[i] = new A;
}
```

then some place else similarly populate the contents of the struct (creating name, data and image using malloc/new).

Now if I say `delete[] array;`, will all the memory allocated so far ( for char*, float*, int**, structure and the array) get destroyed?

Comment: You should use a class instead of a struct and define an explicit destructor for this.

Comment: No, it's not recursive. Also, `A** array = new A[n];` either has one too many `*` or one too few. @Ben There's no difference between `class` and `struct` in C++ other than the default access specifier.

Comment: @T.C. Sure, but that doesn't mean a class shouldn't be used here. It would be cleaner and if this is to be expanded to have functions etc it may go into a header/cpp file set? Seems like just using a class would be a better idea.

Comment: @Ben And you can put all of the functions etc. in a `struct` equally as well. There's no reason to use one over another except perhaps style.

Comment: @Ben The choice between `class` and `struct` is purely style or convention. There's no fundamental difference at the language level. You can express exactly the same types using either.

Comment: Yep, I didn't know that, you learn something new every day. Thanks @T.C., jaunchopanza

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

If you want more automatic memory management, use vectors.

```
struct A {
   string name;
   vector<float> data;
   vector<vector<int>> image;
}
```

Comment: You should make that no, bold and huge, for dramatic effect!

Comment: It might be worth noting SmartPtr/shared_ptr/auto_ptr here, they provide automatic resource handling as well while still having the pointer-style behavior

Comment: shared_ptr doesn't work with C arrays though (unless you provide a custom deleter, which gets a bit complicated).

Answer (score 5):

Nope. For that to happen you'd have to provide a destructor (but be careful in that case when copying the structure, if you don't implement correctly or delete the copy constructor you end up with double `delete`s).

Actually, a better idea would be to use standard library containers instead of raw pointers - since they provide their own destructors, they get destroyed automatically (and you don't have to worry in case of copy, since they implement proper copy semantic).

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you provide an appropriate destructor that does so.